# JQuery AJax - loading timer

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using an Ajax method to retrieve data, is there a way I can implement a loading timer while the process is being carried out?

Cheers

Comment: Unhide a spinning gif before AJAX, hide it on complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well seeing that the load time will vary a timer might not be the best option but what you could do is have an image as such

`<img src="preloader.gif" id="Preloader" style="display:none;" />` You can get some from [preloaders.net](http://preloaders.net)

Then in the jQuery if that's what you are using. Show the preloader before the request.

```
$("#Preloader").show();
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    // On success hide the preloader
    $("#Preloader").hide();
  },
  error: function(){
    // On error hide the preloader as well
    $("#Preloader").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: copy/paste typo - call `.hide()` on success ;o)

Answer (score 3):

Add an `ajaxLoader.gif` spinny animated image in a `div` with `style="display:none;"` css then at the start of your AJAX postback, call `.show()` then `.hide()` again on the callback when the query completes. You can also use `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxComplete()` events if you want to show/hide the loader for all AJAX postbacks.

Comment: Great idea on using `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxComplete()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.ajaxStart()` and `$.ajaxComplete()` which allow you to bind handlers whenever an Ajax call is started/finished.

Otherwise I don't think there's any way to of measuring the progress of a call.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do an actual timer since the call is asynchronous and there is no way of telling when/if the request will be completed.  If you are using jQuery you can utilize the ajaxStart()/ajaxComplete() method to show a loading image or something.